# Libgdx GDXFacebook publish permissions

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, libgdx

Facebook sdk can only login either with read permission or publish permission, but what if I want both? I only need read permission when logging in to register a user or to authenticate it.

So I thought the right way was to first `signIn` with `SignInMode.READ` and then `signIn` again but now with `SignInMode.PUBLISH`

The problem is when I try to sign in the second time, it just load the accessToken, I tried to put `facebook.signOut()` in between but nothing...

```
facebook.signIn(SignInMode.READ, readPermissions, new GDXFacebookCallback<SignInResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SignInResult result) {
        // Login successful
        clientManager.login(result.getAccessToken().getToken());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(GDXFacebookError error) {
        // Error handling
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFail(Throwable t) {
    }
});

//after the user log ins, the app ask for publish permissions, and I
// try to get it by logging in again but now wit `SignInMode.PUBLISH` like so....

facebook.signIn(SignInMode.PUBLISH, publishPermissions, new GDXFacebookCallback<SignInResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(SignInResult result) {
         // Login successful
         clientManager.login(result.getAccessToken().getToken());
     }

     @Override
     public void onError(GDXFacebookError error) {
         // Error handling
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancel() {
     }

     @Override
     public void onFail(Throwable t) {
     }
 });
```

What im trying to ask here is how I get an accessToken capable of publishing after I singin with `SignInMode.READ`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the developer of gdx-facebook extension.

You are doing it correctly,  sign in with read permissions first and then follow with publish permission.

There are 2 cases:

1. You did not authorize the app yet or did authorize the app with less permissions than the ones you request.
   -> you get a new token, which contains all existing and newly requested permissions. All existing tokens become invalid.
2. You already have granted all the requested permissions.
   -> you get the latest token.

---

> What im trying to ask here is how I get an accessToken capable of
>   publishing after I singin with SignInMode.READ?

Just request the permission you need, you get either a new upgraded token which contains old and new permissions or an old one which already contains the permissions.

It is likely that you already granted the permissions and thats why the token does not change. Look in your FB settings -> apps to see which permissions you granted. 
Tokens often look similar the first 10-20 characters. Don't get confused by that.